# Datagrid column header button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I have a button in the header of a datagrid column, but it is not binding to the property on the view model.

Here is the XAML:

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding BillingHistoryList}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ar_bill_dt}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                    <Button Content="Bill Date" Command="{Binding SortData}" />
                </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Amount" Binding="{Binding ar_orig_amt}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Running Total" Binding="{Binding RunningTotal}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

The data is displayed in the grid, but when I press the button it does not execute.  The error in the output is:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error:
>   'SortData' property not found on 'object' ''Button' (Name='')'.
>   BindingExpression:Path=SortData; DataItem='Button' (Name=''); target
>   element is 'Button' (Name=''); target property is 'Command' (type
>   'ICommand')

If I move the button outside the datagrid, it works.  I'm guessing that the problem is the path to the button property, but I don't know how to specify it so that it works.

What do I need to do to get the button to work?

Here's the pertinent parts of the view model:

```
public class BillingHistoryViewModel: ValidatingBindableBase, IRegionManagerAware, INavigationAware
{
    public IRegionManager RegionManager { get; set; }

    private ICustomerService _service;
    private ITransactionHistoryService _trnsService;
    private string _Title;
    public string Title { get => _Title; set => SetProperty(ref _Title, value); }

    public BillingHistoryViewModel(ICustomerService service, ITransactionHistoryService trnsService)
    {
        Title = "Billing History";
        _service = service;
        _trnsService = trnsService;
        SortData = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteSortData);
    }

    private void ExecuteSortData()
    {
    }


    void GetBillingHistory(int account)
    {
        var CustId = _trnsService.GetCustId(account);

        var BillHistList = new List<BillHist>();

        var BillHistoryEntries = _trnsService.GetEntriesByCustId(CustId);

        decimal runningTotal = 0.0m;

        foreach(var entry in BillHistoryEntries)
        {
            var newEntry = new BillHist(entry);

            newEntry.RunningTotal = runningTotal;
            runningTotal += newEntry.ar_orig_amt.Value;

            BillHistList.Add(newEntry);
        }

        BillHistList.Add(new BillHist() {ar_bill_dt=DateTime.Now, ar_orig_amt=10.0m, RunningTotal = 100.0m });
        BillingHistoryList = new ListCollectionView(BillHistList);
    }


    private ICollectionView _BillingHistoryList;
    public ICollectionView BillingHistoryList { get => _BillingHistoryList; set => SetProperty(ref _BillingHistoryList, value); }

    public DelegateCommand SortData { get; set; }
}
```

When I set a break point on ExecuteSort, it never gets there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In that `DataGridTextColumn`, the DataContext is going to be the billing history item (whatever's in BillingHistoryList), not the owner of the collection of billing history items. That's why `{Binding ar_bill_dt}` works: `ar_bill_dt` is surely a property of the billing history item.

If `SortData` is a property of the same viewmodel that owns `BillingHistoryList`, try this:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding BillingHistoryList}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ar_bill_dt}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                <Button 
                    Content="Bill Date" 
                    Command="{Binding DataContext.SortData, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}" 
                    />
            </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Amount" Binding="{Binding ar_orig_amt}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Running Total" Binding="{Binding RunningTotal}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Another version. This is a more respectable way of doing it anyhow:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ar_bill_dt}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button 
                Content="Bill Date" 
                Command="{Binding DataContext.SortData, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}" 
                />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Comment: Here's the error message I get with that: _System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.SortData; DataItem=null; target element is 'Button' (Name=''); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')_

Comment: @Ken Odd. I tested this your XAML and it worked. See my update.

Comment: I copied and pasted your code and it still won't work. I'm using Prism, but I don't think that is causing the problem.  The data context is obviously working for everything except this button! :(

Comment: I added my view model to my original post.

Comment: @Ken Thanks. No surprises there though. What if you name the grid `x:Name="BillingHistoryListGrid"` and bind `Command="{Binding DataContext.SortData, ElementName=BillingHistoryListGrid}" `? That works for me. Also see update. If none of these work, I don't know what to say. I can't do anything to break it, so I can't reproduce whatever you're seeing.

Comment: OK. I didn't put the x:Name in there, but changed it to use the header template you put in your update. IT WORKED!!!  Thank you so much, Ed!  Can you point me in the right direction to get more information on how to do this correctly?  I'm having difficulty finding good information on using XAML in WPF.

Comment: I haven't read [this stuff](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/blog-articles/), but the author is active with WPF on SO, knows the subject well, and communicates well. I saw somebody recommend a book in a comment today, but I can't find it now. If my answer resolved the problem, you can accept it as "correct" by clicking the checkmark.

Comment: @Ken Got that book recco: ["WPF Unleashed" by Adam Nathan](http://www.adamnathan.net/wpf/). Can't vouch for it personally, but it's recommended by somebody who really knows the subject himself.

Comment: Thanks Ed. I’ll check it out.